# MongoDB Aggregation Framework - How to Match by Date Range, Group By Days, and Return Average For Each Day?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm just learning about MongoDB's Aggregation Framework, and I'm wondering if someone can help me improve this query to do the following:

- Find/Match Records with Dates in between a submitted range
- Group the results by Day
- Return Averages for each Day

Here is my model, there are some helpful properties to make writing this query this easier, like the `day` property...

```
// Model
var PriceHourlySchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    day: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    hour: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    }
}, 
{ 
    autoIndex: true 
});
```

Here is my query so far, this only returns a Total Average for all dates included within the range, and does not group by days and return averages for each day, so you can $group by `day`...

```
var start       = moment.utc(req.query.start).startOf('year').toDate();
var end         = moment.utc(req.query.start).add('years',1).startOf('year').add('hours',1).toDate();

PriceHourly.aggregate([
    { $match: { date: { $gt: start, $lt: end } } },
    { $group: { _id: null, price: { $avg: '$price' } } }
], function(err, results){
    console.log(results); 
}); // PriceHourly();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the `_id` you are using for $group.  You should group by `$day` rather than `null`, if you want to group the results by day.  Try this:

```
PriceHourly.aggregate([
    { $match: { date: { $gt: start, $lt: end } } },
    { $group: { _id: "$day", price: { $avg: '$price' } } }
], function(err, results){
    console.log(results); 
});
```

That said, you do not need to store the day and hour as separate elements in the document.  It's redundant data.  You can extract the `day` and `hour` from `date` field in the aggregation query using the [`Date Aggregation`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) operators.

Comment: That query is gona be slow if you have large documents.