# MongoDB - Get counts of registered and confirmed users each day fro a range of dates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My `Users` collection has the following structure:

```
{
    ...
    createdAt: Date,
    confirmedAt: Date // can be null, meaning the user had not confirmed his e-mail
}
```

`createdAt` hold the date the user have registered at the site, `confirmedAt` holds the date the user have confirmed his email.

I can query for a specific date and get the total of users along with how many users hadn't confirmed their e-mail at that date:

```
db.users.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        createdAt: {
            "$lte": ISODate("2016-09-28")
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: ISODate("2016-09-28"),
        total: {
            $sum: 1
        },
        inactive: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{
                    $or: [{
                        $eq: ["$confirmedAt", null]
                    }, {
                        $gt: ["$confirmedAt", ISODate("2016-09-28")]
                    }]
                }, 1, 0]
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

This yields a result like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ISODate("2016-09-28T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "total" : NumberInt(11904), 
    "inactive" : NumberInt(1328)
}
```

What I need is to have results for a **range of dates** without having to repeat the query for each date.

This would be the result I'm after:

```
[{ 
    "_id" : ISODate("2016-09-28T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "total" : NumberInt(11904), 
    "inactive" : NumberInt(1328)
},{ 
    "_id" : ISODate("2016-09-27T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "total" : NumberInt(11883), 
    "inactive" : NumberInt(1314)
},{ 
    "_id" : ISODate("2016-09-26T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "total" : NumberInt(11852), 
    "inactive" : NumberInt(1311)
}]
```

PS: You don't have to use mongo's aggregation framework. If you can do it by using map-reduce I'm okay with it. Mongoose can be used as well.

- The proposed duplicate does not answers my question. By grouping by the "day" field $sum will only work with numbers from that day. I need to count how many users had registered from the start to each date in the range.

Comment: You just want the total of the `confirmed` and `unconfirmed` of each day? just add in the last `project` pipeline stage: `registered: {$sum: ['$confirmed', '$unconfirmed']}`

Comment: @Tom no, I need the total users I have at each date. It's like take any given day and count the total of confirmed and unconfirmed users TO that date. Not just only ON that date, like my query returns.

Comment: @Alex I'm Ok with 2 queries, but I don't understand your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand correctly your question at first, ignore my comment.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what is the expected result? Please edit your question with examples of documents and example of expected output. It will be easier to understand.

Comment: @Tom I have changed the code to reflect the kind of result I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB Aggregation Framework - How to Match by Date Range, Group By Days, and Return Average For Each Day?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771599/mongodb-aggregation-framework-how-to-match-by-date-range-group-by-days-and-r)

Comment: @Paul that's not what I want. By grouping by the "day" field $sum will only work with numbers from that day. I need to count how many users had registered from the start.

Comment: mmm ok, let me see if I understand correctly. Let's say that in the 28th you have 1 total and in the 29th you have also 1, what you want to present in the 29th `total` field is the sum of 28th and 29th? 2? each day present the sum of all the days before including the current date?

Comment: @Tom Yes, exactly.